# Вывод превью E-Mail на сайте перед отправкой пользователю

Tags: html, вёрстка-email

Появилась идея выводить E-Mail админу перед отправкой пользователю. Но возник вопрос - как сделать так, чтобы стили сайта не влияли на вёрстку письма?

Сначала подумал использовать `<iframe>`, но не знаю, правильный ли это юзкейс для него. Плюс, как я понял `<iframe>` требует указания в теге `src` URI, с которого браузер будеи брать содержимое, а у меня содержимое строится динамически и вставляется непосредственно в вёрстку.

Сам сайт использует Bootstrap 2 CSS, бэкенд на PHP.

Ниже пример, как бы я хотел это видеть. Сразу предупреждаю, этот пример показательный и я его написал только для этого вопроса.

```css
.mail-preview {
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.usebootstrap.com/bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!-- Тут сайт, работает со стилями Bootstrap -->

<div class="mail-preview">
  <!-- Тут вёрстка E-Mail, Bootstrap её не трогает -->
  Письмо которое выглядит ровно так как будет у пользователя
</div>

<!-- Снова сайт -->
<form class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="control-group">
    <label for="email" class="control-label">Отправить по адресу</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <input type="email" name="address" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <div class="controls">
      <button id="confirm-send" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
        Отправить это письмо
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Покопавшись в гугле и обдумав задачу, я понял, что лучший способ - сбросить все CSS свойства для класса `email-preview` на "заводские" (user-agent styles).

Сделать это можно с помощью CSS-свойства `all: revert`, но оно не относится к стандарту CSS3, и, по факту, не поддерживается почти нигде ([см. тут](https://caniuse.com/#search=css%20revert)).

Ещё один способ - использовать `css: initial`, оно как раз есть в CSS3, но это свойство не сбросит не только пользовательский CSS, но и "заводские", например, уберёт `display: block` у `div`.

Чтобы сделать именно независимый превью HTML-кода, придётся сэмулировать поведение `all: revert`, применив сначала `all: initial`, а потом прописав стили для всех элементов.

```css
.email-preview, .email-preview * {
  all: initial;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, div {
  display: block;
}

/* И ТАК ДАЛЕЕ */
```

P. S. CSS-свойство `all` не работает в IE, Edge и Opera Mini, но по факту оно лишь сахар для указания значений по умолчанию во всех свойствах. Сюда этот полифилл я вставлять не буду, найти его можно [в ответе на англоязычном StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15903168/9690114), оттуда же и информация для этого ответа.